# site collection content db ldf file consumes huge space in C drive

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, content-database, content

I am having a site collection and it has dedicated content db. We have uploaded documents and now the size has become huge. when I checked the ldf file in sql server location am seeing the size is  18GB +.
Can anyone  help how to delete content of this db and free up the C drive space. i tried to shrink this content through sql management console. but the next day again its filled up with space and now my c drive is having some 30  kbytes of memory only. Mine is a dev machine with SP 2013 and sql server 2012 is installed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1st thing, it is really bad idea having SQL Database(Ldf, MDF) on C drive, becuase this system drive and if it get fill then everything goes down.

You should move the sql data to different drive. Now can you check from Central Admin, that what is the size of site collection? May be you have the same amount of data on it.

then also on SQL Server check how much free space in the content db( `SP_spaceused`). Also what is auto growth rate of the content DB.

final thing, directly manipulating the data in the content database will put u in unsupported mode from MSFT.

To Move the Database to differnt drive, You have to detach the DB from SQL and move the files and attach to sql again.

Check this blog for more informations: 
[Moving a SharePoint 2010 Content Database to a Different Drive](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adminian/archive/2012/08/16/moving-a-sharepoint-2010-content-database-to-a-different-drive.aspx)

[Moving User Databases](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345483%28v=sql.105%29?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

If you run the SP_Helpfile sql command against the content db at sql you will see the autogrowth settings.

https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/database-administration/sql-server-database-growth-and-autogrowth-settings/

Comment: thanks for your reply and time,@Waqas Sarwar. Its my dev env. Can you please elaborate how to move sql data to a different drive. i have unheard of sp_spaceused. i will try this. also how to check the auto growth rate of content db.

Comment: check my updated anwser.

Comment: Hi @Waqas, I have stopped the sql server and agent from services.msc and  copied the problematic databases to D drive and deleted the  mdf an ldf from C drive.